# How to show #s in vertical from Horizontal through simple regex?

Tags: regex, editplus

I have the following numbers as shown below:

```
1234567890
```

I would like to get the result as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

(Horizontal to Vertical). Please help me to achieve it via simple regex or through editplus.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regular expression for this; all you're trying to accomplish is to insert a newline character between each element in your string.

If you're using C#, you can use the following:

```
string s = "1234567890";
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s.ToCharArray());
```

Note that if your number is of a numeric data type (e.g., `int`), you'll likely need to convert it to a string. In C#, this is as simple as calling the `.ToString()` method, for example:

```
int x = 1234567890;
string s = x.ToString();
```

Comment: Your use of Environment.NewLine is exceptional :-) :-) I hadn't ever used it... I normally simply added a \n . (to be clear... I think it's more informative the Environment.NewLine than the rest of the response)

Answer (score 3):

sorry I don't have editplus, but this should work (tested in notepad++)

Find:

```
([0-9])
```

replace:

```
\1\r\n
```

make sure to have regular expression search on (this may only pertain to notepad++)

the () creates a regular expression group, that may then be [back referenced](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html) via the "\1" (see the link for a primer)
the "\r\n" are just CRLF

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have even tried it for alphabets and it works ([a-z]). But i replaced as "\1\n". If i replace with "\1\r\n", the result is occuring with "\r" on edit plus.  Also, if i have a set of information which is both alphabets & digits what is the best way to get the result in veritical order.  EG:  if a horizontal line looks "123456Yuiabcd9034", i would like to get a result in vertical order.

Comment: Then use `([0-9a-zA-Z])` this will find all numbers and letters

Comment: agreed with @stema, that will capture numeric, and lower and upper alpha

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.` with `&\n` in editplus.